# CLLocationManager permissions iOS 11 and iOS 10

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, cllocation

In my application I am using `CLLocation` services in one of my `ViewController`.
Should I ask user for permission in `appdelegate` or in that particular `ViewController`.
If I add permission request code in particular `ViewController` it will not ask permission until user `navigate` to that view controller.
Is this correct implementation?

Comment: You can ask for permission from user in particular view controller. If user denies and you need it to move ahead, show an alert with error and navigate back to previous screen. This would be an ideal approach.

Answer (score 0):

You should ask the user for permission, when the GPS functionality is actually required, so I would do this in the ViewController and not in the AppDelegate.

Comment: I am using it for adding compass at that view

Comment: Then I would ask the user for permission and only add the compass if the user has granted access to use GPS. Add a generic information view instead (if the user did not grant permission).